# Arm Template -VM from existing vnet and all dependent resources

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I want to create ARM template to deploy Azure VM on its already created dependent resources. Want to deploy a vm on these existing dependent resources : Storage Account, Diagnostic Storage Account, Virtual Network, Network Interface, Public IP Address, Network Security Group.

Comment: Please ask a precise question, or explain where you encounter the difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use those dependent resources as parameter and use it in your arm file.

Comment: Done giving every details in parameters but now want to auto take the values of existing resources and just directly deploy the vm.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of this example:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-different-rg-vnet

And update the ARM template according to your requirements.